# How to make a function in Python that will output the content of e.g. cs go items based on the given steamid?

Tags: python, steam, steam-web-api

I'm trying to write a script that will retrieve data about a player's Steam inventory based on Steam id something like how the web site  https://csgobackpack.net  works.

I used examples from the Internet for example:

```
def parseInventory(steam64):
    your_url = "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/"+steam64+"/inventory/json/730/2"
    print(your_url)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(your_url) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
        print(data)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to be authorized to perform this request.

Without authorization I'm getting  `{'success': False, 'Error': 'Unsupported request'}` response.

The simplest way is to copy `steamLoginSecure` cookie straight from browser session and pass it to request.

```py
import requests

cookie = {'steamLoginSecure':'your_cookie'}
res = requests.get('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'+steam64+'/inventory/json/730/2', cookies=cookie)
print(res.json())  # {'success': True, ...
```

Another way is to use `ValvePython/steam` module get authorized session to steam site:

```py
import steam.webauth as wa

user = wa.WebAuth('login')
session = user.cli_login('password')
res = session.get("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/" + steam64 + "/inventory/json/730/2")
res.json()
```

Comment: I thought it was possible to do without authorization because I want to make a function that will be for any user without logging in. So there must always be authorization? And how this site that i mentioned works without authorization?

Comment: Try to get data with using steam api web key. This key is bounded to your application and can grant access similar to authentificated user